# Mongodb DB - Find document with non Json compatible data

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I have a MongodDB collection with approx. 3M documents. However I can't export it to JSON since one or more docs have non json compatible fields. This is fine for MongodDB since docs are stored as BSON, however this don't work for my use case.

I wasn't expecting my docs to contain non JSON compatible data. How can I find documents that don't contain JSON information?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script with:

```html
Collection.forEach(function(item) {
  try {
     JSON.parse(item);
   }
  catch(err) {
     db.NoJsonObject.save(item);}
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good start, but doesn't work. This will list all documents in the as invalid.

Comment: @rat It lists all of them as invalid because `ObjectId()` will fail to parse. If you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))`, it will at least eliminate the ones failing due to the ObjectIds

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the mongoexport tool.

Do you really want to "fix" your data or are you simply looking to represent the data in a way you can read with any old JSON reader?

You could simply make one big JSON file as the output using the --jsonArray switch, but be very careful there.  your reader would try to read in all 3 million docs before it gave it to you as an internal representation.

Without the switch, you'd just get one json document per line and you could do something like this to reduce memory needed.

```
while (read_line){
    load_json(line)
    //do something with memory
    free(json)
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
```

appropriate flags will output the file to strict JSON representation consumable by anything that can import JSON.

Comment: `fix` is a bad choice of words. It's not broken... Since BSON fully supports this. But I wasn't expecting my docs to contain non JSON data, so I want to find them and understand what went wrong

Comment: @rat  probably every document has non-JSON type in the _id:((ObjectId)) field.  is there a specific error your seeing in an external tool?